# Ordering by sub string of a field with OPNQRYF

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange, rpgle

I have a requirement where I need to change the order in which records are printed in a Report. I need to order the records by a substring of a field of the records.

There is an OPNQRYF as below before the call to the report RPG is made:

```
 OVRDBF     FILE(MOHDL35) SHARE(*YES)                

 BLDQRYSLT  QRYSLT(&QRYSLT)                  +       
   SELECT((CHARDT *GE &FRDATE  F2)  +                
   (CHARDT *LE &TODATE  F2)  +                       
   (HDPLVL *EQ 'FS'     F2)  +                       
   (HDMPLT *EQ &PLANT   F2))                         

      OPNQRYF    FILE((*LIBL/MOHDL35))       +       
                 QRYSLT(&QRYSLT)             +       
                 KEYFLD(*FILE)               +       
                 MAPFLD((ZONEDT HDAEDT *ZONED 8 0) + 
                        (CHARDT ZONEDT *CHAR 8))
```

One way I see how to do this is to do a RUNSQL to create a temp table in qtemp with the MOHDL35 records in the required order. The substr SQL function would help to achieve this much easier. This should have the same structure as that of MOHDL35 (FIELD NAMES, RECORD FORMAT)

Then replace the use of this file in the RPG program with the newly created table name. I havent tried this yet, but would this work? does it sound like a good idea? Are there any better suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try creating a view with all the table fields plus the substring'd column, and then use OPNQRYF with that instead of the table, specifying the substring'd column as the KEYFLD. That would probably be simpler (& potentially quicker) than copying the whole lot into QTEMP every time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will try this. The records need to be ordered on the basis of 3 substrings of the same field.

Comment: So that'll probably mean 3 extra columns on the view (I think you can specify multiple columns on KEYFLD although I admit it is a loonnngg time since I used OPNQRYF in anger).

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with `OPNQRYF` by using the `MAPFLD` parameter like this:

```
OPNQRYF FILE((JCVCMP))                  
        KEYFLD((*MAPFLD/PART))          
        MAPFLD((PART '%SST(VCOMN 2 5)'))
```

The fields in `JCVCOMN` are now sorted like this:

```
VENNO  VCMTP  VCMSQ  VCOMN
-----  -----  -----  -------------------------
1,351  ICL    3      Let's see what wow
1,351  ICL    1      This is a test
1,351  NDA    2      another comment
1,351  NDA    1      more records
```

Notice that the records are sorted by the substring of VCOMN starting with the second character.

So here is your `OPNQRYF` with multiple key fields specified

```
OPNQRYF FILE((*LIBL/MOHDL35))                               
        QRYSLT(&QRYSLT)                                     
        KEYFLD((*MAPFLD/CHARDT) (*MAPFLD/HDPROD))           
        MAPFLD((ZONEDT HDAEDT *ZONED 8 0) (CHARDT ZONEDT *CHAR 8)
               (HDPROD '%SST(HDPROD 1 2) *CAT %SST(HDPROD 10 12) 
               *CAT %SST(HDPROD 13 16)'))
```

Some notes: I am guessing that HDAEDT is a `PACKED` number. If so, you don't need to map it to a `ZONED` number just to get it to a character value. If you need the `ZONED` value, that is ok (but `PACKED` should work just as well). Otherwise, you can just use:

```
MAPFLD((CHARDT HDAEDT *CHAR 8))
```

Also in your `OVRDBF`, you need to make sure you choose the correct Override Scope `OVRSCOPE`. The IBM default is `OVRSCOPE(*ACTGRPDFN)`. OPNQRYF also has a scope `OPNSCOPE`. You need to make sure that the `OVRSCOPE`, the `OPNSCOPE`, and the program using the table all use the same activation group. There are a lot of different combinations. If you can't make it work, you can always change them all to `*JOB`, and that will work. But there is nothing intrinsic about `OPNQRYF` that prevents it from working from a CLP.

Comment: Two issues found with this approach. 1) Doesnt work when the program is CLP. Needs to be changes to CLLE. Im not sure if that will cause any unwanted impact. Also how to do this for multiple conditions?OPNQRYF    FILE((*LIBL/MOHDL35)) QRYSLT(&QRYSLT) +      
             KEYFLD((*MAPFLD/HDPROD)) MAPFLD((ZONEDT +  
             HDAEDT *ZONED 8 0) (CHARDT ZONEDT *CHAR +  
             8) (HDPROD '''%SST(HDPROD 1 2)''  *CAT  +  
             ''%SST(HDPROD 10 12)'' *CAT  +             
             ''%SST(HDPROD 13 16)'''))                                              
 Tried a few things.

Comment: It should work the same for CLP and CLLE. The scoping on the override may be the difference. Are you mixing ILE and OPM? That can cause issues if you don't get the scoping correct.

Comment: Mixing? It’s an rpgle and a clp. Is that what you mean by mixing

Comment: RPGLE and CLP might mix execution environments. The CLP always runs in the default activation group. The RPGLE may or may not run in the default activation group.

Comment: What do you mean by multiple conditions?

Comment: I need to order by multiple substrings of the same field as in my earlier comment how can I do this?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: create multiple mapped fields, and add them all to the `KEYFLD` parameter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171099/discussion-between-jmarkmurphy-and-theju112).